# Optimizing Azure App Service Performance: Troubleshooting Slowness in Detail

Tags: performance, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

How can I troubleshoot the slowness of my Azure App Service with a microservices architecture and separate databases for each API? The CPU and memory usage on the Azure App Service plan seem normal, but clients are experiencing slowness during production hours. I want to investigate the root cause of the slowness in more detail. Although APIs are already integrated with Azure Application Insight, providing performance and failure information, when a client reports that the system is slow at runtime, what measures should I take to identify the bottleneck causing the slowness, whether it's at the API level or the database level.

Answer (score 0):

You can analyze the duration of your request between your components. If your request-response time is 2 seconds in service A, you need to understand whether this time is being consumed waiting for service B's or the database's answer and recursively. Look at your traces with App Insight to find this [correlation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/distributed-trace-data). Then, when slower components are found, look at the code to understand why it is slow. You may also have performance issues due to the network, so don't forget to compare the request duration from the sender's and the receiver's points of view. The performance and application map will provide helpful information about that.